# Indexing arrays in python (moore neighborhood)

Tags: python, numpy

The main problem is when I `print cells[i-1][j]` for `i = 2` and `j = 1` it should return 1, but it says there is 0. I want to count neighborhoods of each cell, but this doesn't work properly---but it should.

I have a 3 x 3 matrix, add extra edges with zeros to avoid going out of array, and then have 2 for-loops over my original area with values to count the neighbors. But this counting is broken.

```
import numpy as np
def get_generation(cells, generations):
cells=np.array(cells)
for k in range(generations):

    cells=np.c_[np.zeros(cells.shape[0]), cells,np.zeros(cells.shape[0])]
    cells=np.r_[[np.zeros(cells.shape[1])], cells, np.zeros(cells.shape[1])]]

    for i in range(1, cells.shape[0]-1):     #vertical
        for j in range(1, cells.shape[1]-1):     #horizontal
            neighbours=0
            neighbours+=sum(cells[i-1][j-1:j+2])
            print neighbors, cells[i-1][j-1], cells[i-1][j], cells[i-1][j+1]
            print i, j
            neighbours+=sum(cells[i+1][j-1:j+2])
            neighbours+=cells[i][j-1]
            neighbours+=cells[i][j+1]
    return cells

start = [[1,0,0],
         [0,1,1],
         [1,1,0]]

get_generation(start, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably extract the summation of the neighbors in a helper function, in which you could use a try-except block to avoid testing the boundaries of the array:

somethink like this, maybe:

```
import numpy as np


MOORE_OFFSETS = [(1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1)]


def get_moore_neighbors_sum(array_of_arrays, row, col):
    sum_neighbors = 0
    for neighbor in MOORE_OFFSETS:
        dr, dc = neighbor
        try:
            if row + dr >= 0 and col + dc >= 0:
                sum_neighbors += array_of_arrays[row+dr][col+dc]
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return sum_neighbors


array_of_arrays = # a sequence of sequence of your data
rows = len(array_of_arrays)
cols = len(array_of_arrays[0])

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):

        sum_neighbors = get_moore_neighbors_sum(array_of_arrays, row, col)
```